# How Do I change the jdk of the install4j 7.0.11 IDE?

Tags: java, ide, install4j, java-11, java-10

our project uses helper classes, compiled with java11, which are used in installer scripts. When running the debug installer I get messages like

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

So I think I have to change the jdk of the ide to java11, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fgound it myself in the install4j help: https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/scripts.html
There can be configured an external jdk for cscript compiling. Since install4j 7.0.7 Java-10 and Java-11 is supported.